# Is there rule which Gradle follows to save caches files?

Tags: gradle, version, artifacts

With every new **Gradle** version cache directory is changing. But I can't understand how **Gradleware** choose its name. Is there a pattern for this or the name is random chosen?

I try this method with few Gradle versions:

```
task printDependencies << {
    configurations.getByName('compile').each { dependency ->
       println dependency
    }
}
```

And find that

```
╔═══╦════════════════╗
║ver║ caches dir     ║
╠═══╬════════════════╣
║2.0║ modules-2      ║
║1.7║ artifacts-26   ║
║1.5║ artifacts-23   ║
╚═══╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Of course it's not random. It's an *internal* data structure that's constantly refined. Users shouldn't have to worry.

Comment: Ok but if we create functionality associated with the cashes how to know which will be the cashes dir in the next Gradle?

Comment: You should only use the (public) APIs, not access the cache directly.